# how am i supposed to handle this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am saving a product in my create action, once it is saved i would like it to redirect it to show action like this.

```
if @product.save
  redirect_to :action => :show
```

and my show action displays the content of the product with the requested id. Since I am redirecting, I would lose all my instance variables. So how to pass the id? Should I use flash for this? Or is there a better way of doing this

Comment: You should also go through rails guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html These things are pretty well documented over there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scaffold generator produces code like:

```
if @product.save
  redirect_to @product
else
  render :new
end
```

Rails will look to use a product_path pointing to the show action with the :id being @product.id

This assumes you have, in your config/routes.rb

Rails 2.X

```
map.resources :products
```

Rails 3.X

```
resources :products
```

Comment: What if there are other cases, like if I have to redirect it to some other controllers show method. I mean, if I save an associated object and after save i would like to show the main object.